# pylint warning about ipaddress

Tags: python-3.8

#!/usr/bin/python3.8

"""
Check for if ip in subnet
"""

import ipaddress

MY_VPC_SUBNETS = ["10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]

MY_VPC_IPS = ["10.16.0.0/12", "172.16.12.0/28", "10.15.90.2/32"]

for network in MY_VPC_SUBNETS:
internal_network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
for my_valid_ip in MY_VPC_IPS:
my_ip = ipaddress.ip_network(my_valid_ip)
if my_ip.subnet_of(internal_network):
print(my_ip, "in subnet", internal_network)

my warning is
check_ip.py:17:11: E1101: Instance of 'IPv4Network' has no 'subnet_of' member (no-member)
check_ip.py:17:11: E1101: Instance of 'IPv6Network' has no 'subnet_of' member (no-member)

Answer (score 0):

your code isn't formatted, but it seems to work fine for me with presumptive formatting:

```
 $ cat test.py
```

```py
import ipaddress

MY_VPC_SUBNETS = ["10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]
MY_VPC_IPS = ["10.16.0.0/12", "172.16.12.0/28", "10.15.90.2/32"]

for network in MY_VPC_SUBNETS:
    internal_network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
    for my_valid_ip in MY_VPC_IPS:
        my_ip = ipaddress.ip_network(my_valid_ip)
        if my_ip.subnet_of(internal_network):
            print(my_ip, "in subnet", internal_network)
```

```
 $ python3 test.py
10.16.0.0/12 in subnet 10.0.0.0/8
10.15.90.2/32 in subnet 10.0.0.0/8
172.16.12.0/28 in subnet 172.16.0.0/12

 $ python3 --version
Python 3.8.7

 $ pylint --disable=C0111 test.py

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 9.00/10, +1.00)
```

the disable is just for missing docstring.